# NodeJS - Express incorrectly executes second route

Tags: node.js, express

I have two routes that match the URL http://localhost:8080/app/users/find but I don't want the second one to be executed because the first is more specific.

In the example below how can I prevent the 'did not stop' message of being written?

```
app.get('/app/users/find', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('route 1');
    res.end('route 1 return');
    next('stop!');
});

app.all('/:controller?/:action?(/|)', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('did not stop');
    res.end();
});
```

1. Not calling `next()` - does not work
2. Calling `next(new Error('something'))` - does not work
3. Returning `false` - does not work
4. Doing nothing - System hangs

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what `next()` does.

If you don't want to run the next handler, don't call that.

Comment: I'm calling with error parameter so it should stop. And even not calling it then it has the same behavior.

Comment: No, an error paramater would be `return next(new Error("stop!"));`, you're calling `next('route')`

Comment: I changed the code as you mentioned but it still prints the message.

Comment: Hi Slaks. You were right about not calling next(). '/favicon.ico' was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There were actually two requests happening. The second one was to `/favicon.ico`